# React native useReducer for dispatching input values form authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reducers

I am new to reactnative, trying to implement simple login form with 2 custom input text and a login button, I am having trouble accessing the updated values

please find my code,

```
const loginReducer = (state, action) => {
  
  if (action.type === LOGIN_FORM) 
{
    const updatedValues = {
      ...state.inputValues,
      [action.input]: action.value,
    };
    const updatedValidities = {
      ...state.inputValidities,
      [action.input]: action.isValid,
    };
    let updatedFormIsValid = true;
    for (const key in updatedValidities) {
      updatedFormIsValid = updatedFormIsValid && updatedValidities[key];
    }
    return {
      formIsValid: updatedFormIsValid,
      inputValidities: updatedValidities,
      inputValues: updatedValues,
    };
  }
  return state;
};

const LoginScreen = (props) => {
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
 
  const intialState = {
    inputValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    inputValidities: {
      email: false,
      password: false,
    },
    formIsValid: false,
  };
  const [formState, dispatchFormState] = useReducer(loginReducer , intialState);
 

 const inputChangeHandler = useCallback(
    (inputIdentifier, inputValue, inputValidity) => {
      dispatchFormState({
        type: LOGIN_FORM,
        value: inputValue,
        isValid: inputValidity,
        input: inputIdentifier,
      });
    },
    [dispatchFormState]
  );

  const authHandler = async () => {

    let action;

   //problem updating state values
      action = authActions.login(
        formState.inputValues.email,
        formState.inputValues.password
      );
   
      await dispatch(action);
      
  };



 <MyInput
            id="email"
            label="E-Mail"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            required
            email
            autoCapitalize="none"
            errorText="Please enter a valid email address."
            onInputChange={inputChangeHandler}
           
          />
          <MyInput
            id="password"
            label="Password"
            keyboardType="default"
            secureTextEntry
            required
            minLength={5}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            errorText="Please enter a valid password."
            onInputChange={inputChangeHandler}
           
          />
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button
              title="Login"
              color="blue"
              onPress={authHandler}
            />
          </View>
```

so in my button click `authHandler` I was expecting,

> Object:
>
> email: "test@test.com"
>
> password: "qwerty123"
>
> but my output is
>
> Object:
>
> email: ""
>
> password: ""
>
> qwerty123: true
>
> test@test.com: true

How would I grab my email and password values and dispatch to my `authactions`?

Please let me know if I am missing anything?

Thanks